# What if the root of a tree is changed?

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, graph-algorithm

Given a tree(By tree , I mean N Nodes  , N-1 edges and it is connected) the root of tree is changed to lets say **r**. Now given another node lets say **t** , you have to find the sum of all nodes in the subtree rooted at **t**.
I was trying to implement it in c++ .

```
std::map<int, std::vector< pair<int,int> > > map;
```

if I iterate over the vector map[t] , I have to ensure that it does not go to a path which leads to **r** . How would I ensure that ? 
Also is there a better way to store a tree in c++ , given the conditions that the root of the tree might change ? I think there will be because the map does not convey anything about a root . :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have your tree stored as a general graph. Hence for a given vertex you don't know which is the arc leading towards the root (i.e. the parent).

The solution very much depends on the context. A simple solution would be a depth first search starting from r and looking for t. As soon as you find t you have found also the parent of t, and you can easily identify the subtree starting from t.

Alternatively you can start from t and look for r. When you find r you have found the parent of t and you can traverse all other arcs to find the subtree of t.

About an alternative representation of the graph, usually it is better to keep a list of vertices and for each vertex keep a list of neighbour vertices as in:

```
std::map<int, std::list<int> >
```